# How to execute a node.js command from a button click on a website?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I'm trying to execute a terminal command on a php webpage with a button click. It is for flying an ArDrone and is a nodejs file, I am able to execute the command by opening terminal, cd to the directory and then execute it by typing in 'node drone.js' and it executes fine. I now have created a webpage where i want to have a button that i can click to execute the file instead of having to go through the terminal. Im not sure if this is even possible within PHP? I have tried the following

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['button']))
{
     exec('desktop/dronenotes/drone.js');
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<p>
    <button name="button">Start Drone</button>
</p>
</form>
</body>
```

This isn't working for me and I've also tried to just execute exec('node drone,js');

Im not sure what to try next, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you did not understand the basic principle. exec runs on the server. Connect and JS in the HTLM so it executes on button click (I'm not really a web programmer).

Comment: Hi, so are you telling me that this won't work for me then or how do I get the exec to run?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to do something like :

```
exec('/path/to/node /path/to/drone.js');
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what i should do for the path to node. How do I get the path for it?

Comment: you can add node.js to your operating system environment variables (it will differ depending on OS), then you don't need to worry about the path, just run exec('node /path/to/drone.js');

Comment: Hi I have tried to google search how to add node.js to the operating system variables but I'm not sure how to do it. Im using mac OS, do you know how it can be added on mac?

Comment: Go to the "Telling your system where to find Node" section of  [this link](http://dandean.com/nodejs-npm-express-osx/)

Comment: Thanks for that I got that all done ok and I can now get it running fine in the terminal by just typing in node desktop/DroneNotes/drone.js but it still won't work from the button on the webpage. I have the following on the webpage, can you see anything wrong with this?                                                                                                     <?php

 if (isset($_POST['button'])) { exec('node desktop/DroneNotes/drone.js'); } ?>
<form method="post">
<p>
    <input type="hidden" name="button" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Start Drone">
</p>
</form>

Comment: Do you get any errors in console? I can't see anything wrong with that though, from there you will need to start debugging from the js side, perhaps put alerts in at certain points in the drone.js file to see if it is being run, or where it stops.

Comment: No there are no errors appearing. It is working fine from the terminal when I run it but from the webpage I just click the button and nothing happens. Would it be that php isn't understanding the node command or should node be working with it fine?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know for sure, I don't see why it wouldn't run. Perhaps check in your web server logs for any clues there. I would also put an alert at the beginning of the drone.js file just to check if its even being called or not.

Comment: Hi I have checked the logs and it is saying "node: command not found"

Comment: When you added node to environmental variables, did you restart your machine? Seems it still isn't finding the node command.

Comment: I hadn't but i have restarted now and it is working! Thanks for your help, its much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons don't generate POST values by themselves.  Use a hidden input:

```
<form method="post">
<p>
    <input type="hidden" name="button" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Start Drone">
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: I think a button with `name="..."` attribute should generate a request as well. You don't need any other input fields.